# Doing many iterations of scipy's `curve_fit` in one go

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Consider the following MWE

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
X=np.arange(1,10,1)
Y=abs(X+np.random.randn(15,9))

def linear(x, a, b):
    return (x/b)**a

coeffs=[]
for ix in range(Y.shape[0]):
    print(ix)
    c0, pcov = curve_fit(linear, X, Y[ix])
    coeffs.append(c0)


XX=np.tile(X, Y.shape[0])
c0, pcov = curve_fit(linear, XX, Y.flatten())
```

I have a problem where I have to do basically that, but instead of 15 iterations it's thousands and it's pretty slow.

Is there any way to do all of those iterations at once with `curve_fit`? I know the result from the function is supposed to be a 1D-array, so just passing the args like this

```
c0, pcov = curve_fit(nlinear, X, Y)
```

is not going to work. Also I think the answer has to be in flattening `Y`, so I can get a flattened result, but I just can't get anything to work.

**EDIT**

I know that if I do something like

```
XX=np.tile(X, Y.shape[0])
c0, pcov = curve_fit(nlinear, XX, Y.flatten())
```

then I get a "mean" value of the coefficients, but that's not what I want.

**EDIT 2**

For the record, I solved with using Jacques Kvam's set-up but implemented using Numpy (because of a limitation)

```
lX = np.log(X)
lY = np.log(Y)
A = np.vstack([lX, np.ones(len(lX))]).T
m, c=np.linalg.lstsq(A, lY.T)[0]
```

And then `m` is `a` and to get `b`:

```
b=np.exp(-c/m)
```

Comment: Is the (apparently misnamed) function `linear` the actual function that you want to fit, or is that a simplification of a more complicated function?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser It's the actual function. (Yeah, about the name, I was going to do a linear example, but changed at the last minute, my bad!)

Comment: OK, thanks.  One more pedantic question: in your example, you create `Y` by adding noise created with `randn()`  to `X`.  This means `Y` could have negative values.  Could your real data have negative values?  Also, could the real `Y` contain 0?

Comment: I lied--yet one more question (but it is really part of the previous question): in your real data, does `X` include 0?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser All fair questions considering it's a power law! The data can only have positive values. `X=0` is not considered for the purposes I want! I have edited the question to make these remarks a fact on the MWE.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to take logs and use linear least squares?

Comment: @JacquesKvam That's exactly why I was asking those questions. :)

Comment: @JacquesKvam Yes it would, but I fail to see how that would make it easier. Please, enlighten me with an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Least squares won't give the same result because the noise is transformed by log in this case. If the noise is zero, both methods give the same result.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import random as rng
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
rng.seed(0)
X=np.arange(1,7)
Y = np.zeros((4, 6))
for i in range(4):
    b = a = i + 1
    Y[i] = (X/b)**a + 0.01 * randn(6)

def linear(x, a, b):
    return (x/b)**a

coeffs=[]
for ix in range(Y.shape[0]):
    print(ix)
    c0, pcov = curve_fit(linear, X, Y[ix])
    coeffs.append(c0)
```

`coefs` is

```
[array([ 0.99309127,  0.98742861]),
 array([ 2.00197613,  2.00082722]),
 array([ 2.99130237,  2.99390585]),
 array([ 3.99644048,  3.9992937 ])]
```

I'll use scikit-learn's implementation of linear regression since I believe that scales well.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lr = LinearRegression()
```

Take logs of `X` and `Y`

```
lX = np.log(X)[None, :]
lY = np.log(Y)
```

Now fit and check that coeffiecients are the same as before.

```
lr.fit(lX.T, lY.T)
lr.coef_
```

Which gives similar exponent.

```
array([ 0.98613517,  1.98643974,  2.96602892,  4.01718514])
```

Now check the divisor.

```
np.exp(-lr.intercept_ / lr.coef_.ravel())
```

Which gives similar coefficient, you can see the methods diverging somewhat though in their answers.

```
array([ 0.99199406,  1.98234916,  2.90677142,  3.73416501])
```

Comment: You could also use `scipy.linalg.lstsq` or `numpy.linalg.lstsq`.

Comment: Add the noise back, and compare the results computed with the logs to the results produced by `curve_fit`.  In some cases you'll find they are quite different.  Fitting the logs with linear regression effectively weights the data at low x values more than the data at higher x values.

Comment: [Sorry for spamming you!] I'm not saying using linear least squares with the logs of x and y is wrong, but it won't, in general, give the same results as `curve_fit`.

Comment: Yea I removed the noise to get the same answer :) and since he said it's fine to to take logs and use least squares. It's good to point that out though.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser and JacquesKvam I have been using this solution for some weeks now and it works great! However, a similar problem arose, where this solution doesn't work. You might also be interested in looking at this new question, which you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44957705/doing-many-iterations-of-curve-fit-in-one-go-for-piecewise-function)! In this new case the function I'm trying to fit is discontinuous, so it makes it harder. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful in some situations to have the best fit parameters as a numpy array for further calculations. One can add the following after the for loop:

```
bestfit_par = np.asarray(coeffs)
```