# Doing many iterations of curve_fit in one go for piecewise function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm trying to perform what are many iterations of Scipy's `curve_fit` at once in order to avoid loops and therefore increase speed.

This is very similar to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44837793/doing-many-iterations-of-scipys-curve-fit-in-one-go), which was solved. However, the fact that the functions are piece-wise (discontinuous) makes so that that solution isn't applicable here.

Consider this example:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import random as rng
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
rng.seed(0)
N=20
X=np.logspace(-1,1,N)
Y = np.zeros((4, N))
for i in range(0,4):
    b = i+1
    a = b
    print(a,b)
    Y[i] = (X/b)**(-a) #+ 0.01 * rng.randn(6)
    Y[i, X>b] = 1
```

This yields these arrays:

[image]

Which as you can see are discontinuous at `X==b`. I can retrieve the original values of `a` and `b` by using `curve_fit` iteratively:

```
def plaw(r, a, b):
    """ Theoretical power law for the shape of the normalized conditional density """
    import numpy as np
    return np.piecewise(r, [r < b, r >= b], [lambda x: (x/b)**-a, lambda x: 1])


coeffs=[]
for ix in range(Y.shape[0]):
    print(ix)
    c0, pcov = curve_fit(plaw, X, Y[ix])
    coeffs.append(c0)
```

But this process can be very slow depending of the size of `X`, `Y` and the loop, so I'm trying to speed things up by trying to get `coeffs` without the need for a loop. So far I haven't had any luck.

Things that might be important:

- `X` and `Y` only contain positive values
- `a` and `b` are always positive
- Although the data to fit in this example is smooth (for the sake of simplicity), the real data has noise

**EDIT**

This is as far as I've gotten:

```
y=np.ma.masked_where(Y<1.01, Y)

lX = np.log(X)
lY = np.log(y)
A = np.vstack([lX, np.ones(len(lX))]).T
m,c=np.linalg.lstsq(A, lY.T)[0]

print('a=',-m)
print('b=',np.exp(-c/m))
```

But even without any noise the output is:

```
a= [0.18978965578339158 1.1353633705997466 2.220234483915197 3.3324502660995714]
b= [339.4090881838179 7.95073481873057 6.296592007396107 6.402567167503574]
```

Which is way worse than I was hoping to get.

Comment: Better don't `import` anything inside the inner function. Imports may be cached so this is probably not a big performance improvement, but it's considered bad practice.

Comment: In the linked question, I guess, the improved performance is due to the change from a non-linear model to a linear model. With the piecewise function this might not work, though. In that case you are trying to change an n times one-parameter fit to one n-parameter fit. At the moment I do not see how this should increase performance.

Comment: @mikuszefski Yes, exactly. I feel like you're the only one that actually understood my problem.

Comment: Thanks, and just to emphasize in more detail. The linear fit has a closed form solution and does not require iteration, that's why it is significantly faster. Concerning loop versus combined "supermultifit" it shouldn't make a big difference. The loop is probably even faster as matrices get smaller (imagine e.g. solving two n by n vs one 2n by 2n unless you can use a GPU for that). Finally, ans assuming that the slopes are independent, you might think about [multithreading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html to speed this up. Python is probably not the best tool for that.

Comment: ...maybe in combination with [quue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html)

Comment: BTW: one interesting outcome in my tests is: despite my SSD with 1000 files of 5000 data points, the bottleneck actually is loading the data (>10 s), not fitting it (<1 s)!
So once the data is loaded I guess you can easily fit it within a few seconds (assuming large enough RAM)

Answer (score 2):

Here are three approaches to speeding this up.  You gave no desired speed up or accuracies, or even vector sizes, so buyer beware.

#### TL;DR

Timings:

```
len       1      2      3      4
1000    0.045  0.033  0.025  0.022
10000   0.290  0.097  0.029  0.023
100000  3.429  0.767  0.083  0.030
1000000               0.546  0.046

1) Original Method
2) Pre-estimate with Subset
3) M Newville [linear log-log estimate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44975066/7311767)
4) Subset Estimate (Use Less Data)
```

#### Pre-estimate with Subset (Method 2):

A decent speedup can be achieved by simply running the `curve_fit` twice, where the first time uses a short subset of the data to get a quick estimate.  That estimate is then used to seed a `curve_fit` with the entire dataset.

```
x, y = current_data
stride = int(max(1, len(x) / 200))
c0 = curve_fit(power_law, x[0:len(x):stride], y[0:len(y):stride])[0]
return curve_fit(power_law, x, y, p0=c0)[0]
```

#### M Newville [linear log-log estimate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44975066/7311767) (Method 3):

Using the log estimate proposed by M Newville, is also considerably faster.  As the OP was concerned about the initial estimate method proposed by Newville, this method uses `curve_fit` with a subset to provide the estimate of the break point in the curve.

```
x, y = current_data
stride = int(max(1, len(x) / 200))
c0 = curve_fit(power_law, x[0:len(x):stride], y[0:len(y):stride])[0]

index_max = np.where(x > c0[1])[0][0]
log_x = np.log(x[:index_max])
log_y = np.log(y[:index_max])
result = linregress(log_x, log_y)
return -result[0], np.exp(-result[1] / result[0])
return (m, c), result
```

#### Use Less Data (Method 4):

Finally the seed mechanism used for the previous two methods provides pretty good estimates on the sample data.  Of course it is sample data so your mileage may vary.

```
stride = int(max(1, len(x) / 200))
c0 = curve_fit(power_law, x[0:len(x):stride], y[0:len(y):stride])[0]
```

#### Test Code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import random as rng
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.stats import linregress

fit_data = {}
current_data = None

def data_for_fit(a, b, n):
    key = a, b, n
    if key not in fit_data:
        rng.seed(0)
        x = np.logspace(-1, 1, n)
        y = np.clip((x / b) ** (-a) + 0.01 * rng.randn(n), 0.001, None)
        y[x > b] = 1
        fit_data[key] = x, y
    return fit_data[key]


def power_law(r, a, b):
    """ Power law for the shape of the normalized conditional density """
    import numpy as np
    return np.piecewise(
        r, [r < b, r >= b], [lambda x: (x/b)**-a, lambda x: 1])

def method1():
    x, y = current_data
    return curve_fit(power_law, x, y)[0]

def method2():
    x, y = current_data
    return curve_fit(power_law, x, y, p0=method4()[0])

def method3():
    x, y = current_data
    c0, pcov = method4()

    index_max = np.where(x > c0[1])[0][0]
    log_x = np.log(x[:index_max])
    log_y = np.log(y[:index_max])
    result = linregress(log_x, log_y)
    m, c = -result[0], np.exp(-result[1] / result[0])
    return (m, c), result

def method4():
    x, y = current_data
    stride = int(max(1, len(x) / 200))
    return curve_fit(power_law, x[0:len(x):stride], y[0:len(y):stride])

from timeit import timeit

def runit(stmt):
    print("%s: %.3f  %s" % (
        stmt, timeit(stmt + '()', number=10,
                     setup='from __main__ import ' + stmt),
        eval(stmt + '()')[0]
    ))

def runit_size(size):

    print('Length: %d' % size)
    if size <= 100000:
        runit('method1')
        runit('method2')
    runit('method3')
    runit('method4')


for i in (1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000):
    current_data = data_for_fit(3, 3, i)
    runit_size(i)
```

Comment: Great answer. It's amazing how much improvement method 2 gives. I'd never have guessed it makes such a difference! However, the question was about getting rid of the loop, and not just improving performance. So even though I want to reward your answer, I'm unsure if I should accept/reward this answer on this basis. I'm thinking of waiting until the end of the bounty and if there's no better answer I'll reward yours without accepting it. Do you have an opinion on that?

Comment: I don't know what loop you are worried about.  If you are referring to running this on multiple data sets, the loop for each data set will be trivial to any run time of the curve fit itself, if the dataset is of any significant size.

Comment: The dataset is is about 3000 to 4000 points for each fit. It does about 10K fits. Turns out in my data my initial guess was already pretty close to the actual value (which doesn't change much from curve fit to curve fit) so the "stride" trick didn't actually improve performance unfortunately. If you're right about the loop than I think there's not much hope for me to improve then I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

1. Use `numpy.where` (and possibly `argmin`) to find the `X` value at which the `Y` data becomes 1, or perhaps just slightly larger than 1, and truncate the data to that point -- effectively ignoring the data where Y=1.

That might be something like:

```
index_max = numpy.where(y < 1.2)[0][0]
x = y[:index_max]
y = y[:index_max]
```

2. Use the hint shown in your log-log plot that the power law is now ***linear*** in log-log.  You don't need `curve_fit`, but can use `scipy.stats.linregress` on `log(Y)` vs `log(Y)`.  For your real work, that will at the very least give good starting values for a subsequent fit.

Following up on this and trying to follow your question, you might try something like:

```
import numpy as np 
from scipy.stats import linregress

np.random.seed(0)
npts = 51 
x = np.logspace(-2, 2, npts)
YTHRESH = 1.02

for i in range(5):
    b = i + 1.0 + np.random.normal(scale=0.1)
    a = b + np.random.random()
    y = (x/b)**(-a) + np.random.normal(scale=0.0030, size=npts)
    y[x>b] = 1.0

    # to model exponential decay, first remove the values
    # where y ~= 1 where the data is known to not decay...
    imax = np.where(y < YTHRESH)[0][0]

    # take log of this truncated x and y
    _x = np.log(x[:imax])
    _y = np.log(y[:imax])

    # use linear regression on the log-log data:
    out = linregress(_x, _y)

    # map slope/intercept to scale, exponent
    afit = -out.slope
    bfit = np.exp(out.intercept/afit)

    print(""" === Fit Example {i:3d}
          a  expected {a:4f}, got {afit:4f}
          b  expected {b:4f}, got {bfit:4f}
          """.format(i=i+1, a=a, b=b, afit=afit, bfit=bfit))
```

Hopefully that's enough to get you going.

Comment: That is a good idea, except that the actual data I have to fit have noise, so `argmin` is not necessarily the index at which the transition occurs.

Comment: But you probably have some idea of the noise level (relative to 1), and can find a suitable place to truncate the data so that log(y) /is/ linear in log(x) (plus noise).  Or perhaps you could weight the values in the linear regression giving very little weight to y values less than some threshold (say, 5.0 or perhaps 1.5, depending on the noise level).

Comment: I don't see how that could work, since that threshold is ill-defined (meaning it could change in the `0` dimension). But maybe I'm missing something. Maybe you can provide a working example...

Comment: sorry, you don't know how *what* could work?  The threshold does not need to be ill-defined, as you could (as suggested earlier) ignore all values with `x>x_thresh` where `x_thresh` is the lowest value of `x` where `y` is below some threshold (say 2 or 5). that would give you data that *is* linear on a log-log plot, and so could be solved by linear regression methods.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't think I can explain further. See my edit about what I was able to implement. I tried implementing your answer but it just doesn't make sense to me. Again, I'd be happy to give you the bounty and accept the answer if you show me a working example. I just couldn't do it.

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you're saying. But this is not what I'm asking. The performance is improved, so that does help, but you're still doing each curve fit inside a loop. I want to get rid of the loop.

Comment: From what I see you have 4 different curves for which you are trying to fit coefficients.  What makes you think the python loop is a performance problem?  You supplied no benchmarks. If you are worried about performance, using a linear regression will be much faster than an iterative curve_fit().  If you're still worried about performance after that, use multiprocessing.

Comment: I see. First: in my actual example the loop is more than 10K values long, so it might be of importance (although it might not be also, now that I think about it more). Second: due to the noise of the data I can't safely determine where to "cut" the data, which is required in your answer. I tried some things but I can't arrive at a method that always works. And since I need an answer that's as precise as possible I can't "overshoot" the transition by using a very high threshold for `Y`.

Comment: You *ARE* cutting the data by saying "set y for these values to 1".   All you have to do for the linear regression to work both "well" and "fast" is to mask out these values that you have already identified as "not good values, must set to some other value".  There is little penalty for cutting too much data (you could ignore all data with y>1.5 or 5, as suggested earlier), and only a slight increase in error if you cut too little data.