# How to use curve_fit function inside a for loop to create multiple regressions in one go in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, curve-fitting

In a nutshell, I have two matrices, one called t and another called y. Each of them has 7 columns. Let's say they are called a, b, c, d, e, f and g. What I would like is to get a regression from a against a, b against b, ..., g against g for these two matrices.

I have already managed to make my algorithm make a regression using curve_fit for one column at a time. But I really would like is for it to make the 7 regressions in one go. I guess I should use a for loop, but I am not sure how.

In the end, I would like to save the k values in one array and plot that array to see the trend. Unfortunately, I am still stuck in the part where I have to create multiple regressions at the same time.

I think my problem is something similar to this one [Doing many iterations of scipy's `curve_fit` in one go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44837793/doing-many-iterations-of-scipys-curve-fit-in-one-go), but I am failing to apply to my case.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import pandas as pd

file = ('y.xls')
xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)
t = xl.parse('t')
y = xl.parse('y')

y=y.dropna()
t=t.dropna()

def func(x, A, k, C):
    return A * np.exp(-k * x) + C

for i in np.arange(0,6):
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(t.iloc[:,[i]], y.iloc[:,[i]])

    popt[i], pcov[i] = curve_fit(func, t.iloc[:,[i]], y.iloc[:,[i]], p0=([0,1,0]))
    plt.plot(t, func(t, *popt), 'r-',
        label='fit: A=%5.2f, k=%5.4f, C=%5.2f' % tuple(popt))

print(popt)

plt.xlabel('t (h)')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% what I wanted, because I still don't have the graphics for each curve_fit but I managed to find a final solution that suits me (the final trend with each k value for all regressions).

It was based on the person on the link I mentioned, so I have already upvoted it, thank you!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import pandas as pd

file = ('y.xls')
xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)
t= xl.parse('t')
y= xl.parse('y')

y=y.dropna()
t=t.dropna()

y=y.values
t=t.values

y=np.transpose(y)
t=np.transpose(t)

def func(x, A, k, C):
    return A * np.exp(-k * x) + C

coeffs=[]
for ix in np.arange(7):
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, t[ix], y[ix],p0=([1,20,9]))
    coeffs.append(popt)

coeffs=np.transpose(coeffs)
print(coeffs)

plt.plot(np.arange(7)+1, coeffs[1], 'r-')

plt.xlabel('point')
plt.ylabel('k')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```